# How do I echo rows from database that includes the users id?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have a database called invoices and I have the user id in there and the date, I would like the user to be able to see all his invoices but not the others. So like my database is setup like

id | userid | amount | date | status

and I want the user to see his own invoices, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE userid = [the userid of the user];
```

You can also select specific columns of those rows like:

```
SELECT amount FROM invoices WHERE userid = [the userid of the user];
```

If you want more help, you'll have to explain what specifically you need help with!

Hope this helps!

[Helpful Source - SQLCOURSE](http://www.sqlcourse.com/intro.html)

**Edit**

Oh I see what you mean!

When you create a user (using the `INSERT` command), you can use `RETURNING` to ask for information from the rows you just created/populated:

`INSERT INTO invoices (userid, amount, date, status) VALUES ([some userid], [some amount], [some date], [some status]) RETURNING id;`

This is assuming `id` is populated by a serial input. You can also ask for any or all of the other rows you just populated. For example:

`INSERT INTO invoices (id, userid, amount, date, status) VALUES ([some id],
 [some userid], [some amount], [some date], [some status]) RETURNING *;`

Comment: how would i echo each time a new row is created in the database and i want it to be displayed to the user?

Comment: i mean in the table it would store many of the other users invoices and the php code checks the table and only pulls the rows that match the same user id as the user. does this code do that?

Comment: I mean at that point you would just want something like `SELECT id FROM invoices WHERE userid = [the userid you want]`. This would return every row in the relation where the userid equals the one you want. Keep in mind this is the SQL query, not the php code you need to connect to the database.